# asp.net mvc with NHibernate - how to handle many-to-one when saving/creating entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, validation

I have a entity called Worker , and another entity called Company. In the NHibernate mapping of Worker .. I say

```
<many-to-one name="Company" column="CompanyID"/>
```

The classes are

```
public class Company 
{
   public virtual int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual string Name { get; set;}
}
public class Worker
{
   public virtual int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual Company Company { get; set;}
   public virtual CompanyID { get { return Company == null ? 0 : Company.Id;}}
}
```

In my view for creating Worker  I have html form that has a CompanyID input . How to handle creat/update of worker properly in my controller after the user submit the form with a html POST ?  The CompanyID field is read only. How to make TryValidate TryUpdateModel in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the ID when you are using an ORM. Do something like `session.Get<Company>(id)` to retrieve te correct company entity and assign it to the property `Company` of your `Worker` entity.
I will even remove the CompanyID property from your class.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use cascade in this case. You don't want new companies to be created *implicitly* when storing workers. The company needs to be there already.

Comment: that's probably true, I will edit the portion about save-update.

Comment: my html form has a drop-down <select> to pick the CompanyID . Once it is picked and submited to the controller (MVC) , the controller has methods such as TryUpdateModel , and TryValidateModel . Can I reuse TryUpdateModel to save me the amount of codes to copy html form values to the entity ?

Comment: If your application is structured to open a single session per each conversation, once you get the company once ( by id ) the first level cache take care on not issuing other db query for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ASP.NET and the whole stuff, but I can tell you how you should implement it against NHibernate.

You need to pass the properties of the worker including the CompanyID to the server. I suggest to use a DTO instead of passing the entity.

If you need more details, you should explain how you transfer these data to the server.

```
//create a company-proxy. this doesn't touch the database
Company company = session.Load<Company>(companyId);
// assign it the the worker. You need to put the worker into the 
// session somehow before. this depends on your specific server interface
worker.Company = company;
```